# macOS SwiftData app doesn't sync with iCloud when run as app file

Tags: swiftui, cloudkit, swift-data

I face strange behavior of macOS SwiftData app when syncing with iCloud via CloudKit framework. All works fine when the app is built and run from the XCode environment, but when I take the ".app" file from the `../DerivedData/.../Build/Product/Debug` folder and run it, data is downloaded correctly but updates are not going through. For another app the same approach works fine. Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong here?